# Is it possible to use OAuth2.0 for Google Domain Shared Contacts API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-contacts-api, google-authentication

i have to create an app for Google Domain Shared Contacts API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/domain-shared-contacts/#authsub). there are only two methods for Authentication are specified 
1.ClientLogin
2.AuthSubProxy

i dont want to store user's username and password so only option is AuthSubProxy .when i click on this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub it is saying that this method is deprecated .can any one please clear it, we can use OAuth2.0 for google domain shared Contacts api or the only option is to use Deprecated AuthSubProxy method ??please reply !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OAuth can be used to authenticate with the shared contacts API.

[This article](http://www.jellybend.com/2012/12/12/manage-google-apps-domain-shared-contacts-with-google-apps-script/) explains it nicely with an example.